# Find a function that satisfies the condition.

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, continuity, logarithms

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be fixed and $t$ a variable that takes values in the universal covering space of ${\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}}$.

Find a **continuous** function $f(s$) such that
$$|t \log t| = |t| \sqrt{(\ln |t|)^2 + (\arg t)^2} < \epsilon$$
whenever $|t| < f(\arg t)$.

**Note:** Basically, since $t$ is in the universal covering space of ${\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}}$, $\log {t}$ and $\arg {t}$ are well-defined functions and not multi-valued like they usually are.

Comment: Well, any $f \leq 0$ works, vacuously. Did you want $f$ to be positive somewhere, or even everywhere?

Comment: Yeah sorry forgot to mention it. $f$ has to be positive-valued everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New strategy: Replace $\lvert t \rvert$ and $\arg t$ by real variables $r>0$ and $\theta$, respectively. Define $g_\theta \colon \mathbb R_{>0} \to \mathbb R_{>0}$ by $g_{\theta}(r) = r^2((\ln r)^2 + \theta^2)$; note that this last expression is essentially the square of the expression we are interested in. Construct a continuous function $h \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R_{>0}$ so that $g_\theta(r) \leq h(\theta) \cdot r$ for all $r \leq 1$ and $\theta \in \mathbb R$.

**Edit (2014-06-21):** Since the asker has been inactive for almost a month now, I'm just going to write down the full solution and put it in the spoiler block below. Hover your cursor over to unhide the text.

> It suffices to find a continuous function $f \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R_{>0}$ such that for $r>0$ and $\theta$ real, we have $$r^2\bigl((\ln r)^2 + \theta^2\bigr) < \epsilon^2$$ whenever $r < f(\theta)$. Note first that since $\lim_{r \to 0} r (\ln r)^2 = 0$, we can use compactness to argue that the function $r \mapsto r(\ln r)^2$ is bounded on $(0,1]$. Pick an upper bound $\alpha$ (one can use calculus to show that $\alpha = 4/e^2$ is the smallest possible choice). If we now define $f$ by $$f(\theta) = \min\left\{1, \frac{\epsilon^2}{\alpha + \theta^2}\right\},$$ then when $r < f(\theta)$, we obtain $$r^2\bigl((\ln r)^2 + \theta^2\bigr) = r\bigl(r(\ln r)^2 + r \theta^2\bigr) < r\bigl(\alpha + \theta^2\bigr) < \epsilon^2$$ as desired.

Comment: Sorry can you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: @AlexStrife What part are you stuck on, both in terms of the my hint and your whole question? An answer would help me target any further elaboration.

Comment: Well I wasn't sure what you meant by giving an upper bound in terms of $f$. What I have been trying to do is to look for a simpler expression greater than $|t| \sqrt{(\ln {|t|})^2 + (\arg t)^2}$ and making that expression less than $\epsilon$. But the problem I always encounter is that $\ln {|t|}$ becomes negative. I have also been assuming that $|t|$ is less than some constant so that some inequalities hold. I feel that the trick is to  consider $|t| \ln {|t|}$ together but I can't figure out a way that works nicely.

Comment: @AlexStrife Welp, now that you've pointed out where the difficulty lies, I see that my entire thought process was too naïve so my "hint" doesn't really lead anywhere, either. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: @AlexStrife I edited the answer with a new approach, and I think I have the details down this time.

Answer (score -2):

A good strategy I've learned throughout undergraduate mathematics courses is to always simplify, and reword. It usually helps see a problem from a different perspective. Going off this notion, I'll make a few points

1. $|t\log{t}| = |t||logt| = |t|\sqrt{ (ln|t|)^2} + (\arg t)^2)$ 
   So essentially the important parts of this equality is that $|logt| = |t|\sqrt{ (ln|t|)}^2 + (\arg t)^2)$
2. Rewording the problem, your problem is finding f(s) so that

$|t| < f(arg t) \implies |\log(t)| = |t|\sqrt{ (ln|t|)^2} + (\arg t)^2)$

From here, I suggest maybe isolating $\arg t$ so that your new statement is simplified. I think this will provide more insight into solving the problem. Hope this helped, if even a little. And sorry about the poor formatting, still getting used to posting answers. Good luck!

Comment: I don't think the asker has any problem with the equality; it's an immediate consequence of the fact that $\log t = \ln \lvert t \rvert + i \arg t$. The nontrivial part is showing that the two equivalent expressions are less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: Yeah guess I just showed the trivial 10% of the question aha, thanks for the comment.